# Windows 10 using correct resolution on HDMI to TV

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, tv

I have a UHD TV connected over HDMI 2.0, this is the only display. In Windows, resolution is set to 3840x2160@60Hz.
Whenever I turn on my PC first and the TV afterwards, the TV reports an unsupported resolution. Sometimes this also happens when the PC is woken from standby and sometimes the TV reports no input signal instead of wrong resolution, though all the lights on the PC look normal. This can usually be resolved by turning the TV off and on again, sometimes needs to be repeated 2 or 3 times, sometimes I have to reset the PC, which is obviously quite annoying after a while.

There is obviously some handshake failing. When I look at the monitor driver ("Generic PnP Monitor", manufacturer provides no driver and Windows doesn't find an alternative), I can see that Windows assumes that this TV supports resolutions up to 4096x2160. I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but I assumed that perhaps it will default to that resolution when the TV isn't recognized.

Is there a good solution for this problem? I would like to force my PC to just send a 3840x2160 signal over HDMI whenever possible and not reverting to other ports or other resolutions if nothing else is connected. TV is a Samsung HU7200, GPU an Nvidia 1080 Ti with regularly updated Geforce drivers.

Comment: I used to get this with Windows 7 and a Dell monitor, turning off the monitor and back on usually corrected it.

Comment: @RogUE Yeah as I mentioned, that's how I do it too, sometimes 2-3 times, sometimes I have to reset the PC. But it would be much more comfortable not having to use this workaround long term.